# Unwanted Spacing using Sizetofit in uilabel

Tags: ios

I have a UILabel which receives text from database sometime the text may be too short and sometimes it may be long morethan 30 lines to overcome these i am using sizetofit property

```
quranText.numberOfLines = 0
quranText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
quranText.sizeToFit()
```

for that uilabel...But now i am facing spacing issue as you can seen in that image. How to reduce that unwanted spacing?

[image]

Comment: Is it because you have multiples "\n" at the start of your text? You may use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` with `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet`.

Comment: same result nothing reduces of using these.....
 let trimmedString = footNoteResult[k].trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

Comment: Did you set constraints to your label, which may explain the `sizeToFit()` not working. It seems to big, and it's behaviour is to center text vertically.

Comment: i had used frame for uilabel via programmatically...

Comment: Use Autolayout for your label and try sizeToFit() it will give exact size what you want for your dynamic text.